# How can i change layout when scrolling RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my application I should show some data from server and for this items I create option button, when click on this option button show users other data for this item.
Please see below image to know my mean : 
[image]

When click on **"..."** change layout and show other data, and when click on **"✕"** close this layout and show again first layout.

I can show other layout when click on **...** and I can close this layout when click on **✕**.

But, I want when scrolling `recyclerView` close this layout (info layout) and show basic layout (with image), I want this work automatically when scrolling `recyclerView`.

**For example :** If show info layout, when **scrolling** `recyclerView` close this info layout and show again basic layout.

I use this codes in adapter.
**When click on ... button :**

```
    holder.tvTonightOpenMoreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown)
                    .duration(500)
                    .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                            holder.tvTonightOpenMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.tvTonightCloseMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.tvTonightMoreInfoLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                        }
                    })
                    .playOn(holder.tvTonightMoreInfoLay);
        }
    });
```

**When click on ✕ button :**

```
    holder.tvTonightCloseMoreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideOutUp)
                    .duration(500)
                    .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                            holder.tvTonightOpenMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.tvTonightCloseMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                        }
                    })
                    .playOn(holder.tvTonightMoreInfoLay);
        }
    });
```

I want when **scrolling** `recyclerView` call this code :

```
    holder.tvTonightCloseMoreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideOutUp)
                    .duration(500)
                    .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                            holder.tvTonightOpenMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.tvTonightCloseMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                        }
                    })
                    .playOn(holder.tvTonightMoreInfoLay);
        }
    });
```

**Initialize recyclerView in Activity :**

```
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
    filterRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    filterRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    filterRecyclerView.setAdapter(tvTonightAdapter);
```

How can I it? please help me my friend<3

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the scroll events of `RecyclerView` using `OnScrollListener` and change the layout:

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
          @Override
          public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                // close info layout logic...
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

for this you should use one Flag such as boolean.
For this you should get when scrolling recyclerView and pass this flag to adapter.
such as this code :

```
    boolean closeInfoLay = false;
    filterRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0 || dy < 0) {
                closeInfoLay = true;
            } else {
                closeInfoLay = false;
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            }
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    });
```

pass flag to adapter :

```
adapter = new YOURADAPTER(context, model, closeInfoLay);
```

in Your adapter, change you constructor :

```
private boolean closeInfoLay;

public TvToNightListAdapter(Context context, List<ModelList> model, boolean closeInfoLay) {
    this.context = context;
    this.model = model;
    this.closeInfoLay = closeInfoLay;
}
```

then close you layout :

```
    if (closeInfoLay) {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideOutUp)
                .duration(500)
                .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                        holder.tvTonightOpenMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.tvTonightCloseMoreInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                    }
                })
                .playOn(holder.tvTonightMoreInfoLay);

    }
```

I hope help you my friend